# How to pass clicked image from GridView to custom alert dialog

Tags: java, android-studio

In my Android app I've got an activity named Gallery that displays a grid view. Each grid contains a photo. I've got the on click handler built that produces a custom alert dialog with an OK button and an ImageView. I can manually set the ImageView source to a drawable resource (png file) and it displays correctly, but I need to be able to display the image that was clicked (in my grid view) in the custom alert dialog.

Here's my code:

The activity_gallery containing the OnCreate method:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_gallery);

        GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
        gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
        final ImageView clickedImage = new ImageView(this);

        gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                                    int position, long id) {
                loadPhoto(position);

            }
        });
    }
```

And my loadPhoto method which is called from the code above:

```
private void loadPhoto(int position) {

        AlertDialog.Builder imageDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_fullimage_dialog, null);

        ImageView image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.fullimage);

        Resources resources = getResources();

        image.setImageResource(R.drawable.webgallery_1);

        imageDialog.setView(view);
        imageDialog.setPositiveButton(R.string.label_ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){

            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }

        });

        imageDialog.create();
        imageDialog.show();
    }
```

As you can see in the code above, I can set R.drawable.webgallery_1 as the photo's source with no problem. But that would display the same image every time, no matter what photo is clicked.

How or what do I pass from the main code to the loadPhoto method to be able to identify the photo that was clicked? I can pass the position, and that returns an int value of the position of the item that was clicked in the grid view, but I'm unsure of how to use that to set the image resource in the alert dialog to the photo that was clicked.

Answer (score 0):

I got this working after some trial and error. It required me to make changes to the ImageAdapter class. See the changes below:

Main Activity

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_gallery);

        final GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
        gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
        gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                                    int position, long id) {
                Object myObject = gridview.getItemAtPosition(position);

                Integer myInt = ((Integer) myObject);
                loadPhoto(position, myInt);

            }
        });
    }
```

loadPhoto method:

```
private void loadPhoto(int position, Integer myInt) {

        AlertDialog.Builder imageDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_fullimage_dialog, null);

        ImageView image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.fullimage);

        Resources resources = getResources();
        image.setImageResource(myInt);

        imageDialog.setView(view);
        imageDialog.setPositiveButton(R.string.label_ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){

            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }

        });

        imageDialog.create();
        imageDialog.show();
    }

}
```

ImageAdapter class

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;
    public String id;
    //private final String[] mobileValues;
    String myString;

    public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
        //String myList[] = c.getResources().toString();
        //this.mobileValues = myList;

    }

    public int getCount() {
        int myCount = 0;
        Field[] fields = R.drawable.class.getFields();

        for (Field f : fields) {
            myString = f.getName();
            String stub = myString.substring(0, 3);

            if (stub.equals("web")) {
                //String drawableName = "R.drawable." + myString;
                int resID = ((Activity)mContext).getResources().getIdentifier(myString, "drawable", ((Activity)mContext).getPackageName());
                array_image.add(resID);

                myCount++;
            }
        }
        return (myCount);
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {

        return array_image.get(position);
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imageView;

        DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
        ((Activity)mContext).getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
        int screenWidth = dm.widthPixels;

        int imageWidth = screenWidth / 2 - 50;

        if (convertView == null) {
            // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
            imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(imageWidth, imageWidth));
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
            imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
        } else {
            imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
        }

        imageView.setImageResource(array_image.get(position));
        imageView.setTag(myString);
        return imageView;
    }

    private ArrayList<Integer> array_image = new ArrayList<Integer>();

}
```